# Show that dim$(U \cap V) \ge 2$ if U and V are 3-dimensional subspaces of $ K^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that dim$(U \cap V) \ge 2$ if U and V are 3-dimensional subspaces of $ K^4$

I'm absolutely stuck. I know that it is only small, easy proof, but can some show me how it is done?

Comment: Your first reflex should be to search for a relationship between $\dim(U),\dim(V)$ and $\dim(K^4)$, which is exactly what Don's answer does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dim(U+V)=\dim U+\dim V-\dim U\cap V\;\ldots$$

Comment: Short and sweet.